# Docker file with python script to get end of process output

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I have written docker file to call python script that will execute the process and copy the result. On running the python script, it work as expected, but on calling python script with docker it doesn't wait for the subprocess to complete i.e it copy the file before it's generated.
 Python script

```
process = subprocess.Popen('Workflow.exe',shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
  result, errors = process.communicate(timeout=240)
result = list(filter(None, result.decode('utf-8').split('\r')))
if not result:
     copy('.\\output', os.path.join(path, 'output1', 'content'))
  else:
     print('Result: {}'.format(result))
except TimeoutExpired:
  process.kill()
  print('Killed')
```

Docker file

```
FROM python:3-windowsservercore

WORKDIR c:\\Temp

ADD test.py /

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

Comment: Please share the whole Dockerfile with us.

Comment: Added, please have a look.